# Архитектура БД для хранения остатков

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет. Есть БД с таблицами:

- products(id, category_id, name, price)
- components(id, name)
- product_component (product_id, component_id, count)

Возникла необходимость добавить отчетность по наличию компонентов. Думаю реализовать это с помощью 1 таблицы:

- components_storage (type, component_id, count)

Где `type` - это тип действия (закупка, продажа или списание). Но из этого выходит несколько проблем:

1. Большой объем таблицы. Таблица очень быстро заполнится данными, поскольку сейчас ежедневно в базу приходит по ~1000 заказов.
2. Невозможно добавить для каждого типа какие-либо данные. К примеру, для поставки - это поставщик, цена закупки. Для списания - причина списания.

В связи с этим вопрос. Правильно ли будет Разделить закупки, продажи и списания на разные таблицы? Т.е. сделать 3 таблицы: `component_procurements`, `component_sales` и `component_offs`?

Comment: я думаю это не правильно!

Comment: @Yaroslav что именно неправильно и почему?

Comment: разбиение на три таблицы

Comment: *Таблица очень быстро заполнится данными, поскольку сейчас ежедневно в базу приходит по ~1000 заказов.* Не парьтесь. Миллион записей (а это средненько) Вы будете копить три года... *Невозможно добавить для каждого типа какие-либо данные.* Это потому что Вы не добавили в структуру поля для этой информации.

Comment: @Akina дак там и вопрос отчасти в том, стоит ли все в одну кучу добавлять. Так что тут три пути потенциальных, все в одном, в трех разных, и в четырех, где одна основная со всеми движениями, а три - вспомогательные по типам со связью 1-1

Comment: @Akina учитывая, что в среднем на каждый заказ идет по 5-7 компонентов, + сейчас открывается 2 точки, которые будут работать под этой же системой, то получается, что за 3 года это уже будет 15 млн записей. Плюс здесь есть нюанс, что если в одну таблицу засунуть данные про поставщика для поставок, про комментарий для списаний и т.д., то большой объем памяти будет занят нерелевантными полями, которые в 60% случаев будут = NULL. Teran прав, именно это и имел в виду в вопросе

Comment: @Alexxosipov вы привели только поля с поставщиком, ценой и причиной. В действительности то полей будет куда больше? или как?

Comment: Ну 15 миллионов... тоже не дофига, в общем. Да и не вижу я особой разницы - одна таблица на 15кк или три по 5кк. Вариант одной таблицы сложнее в части контроля целостности (и весьма желательна серверная логика корректировки данных), в случае нескольких - сложнее запросы на получение совокупной и итоговой информации. А частные данные типа в суммарную отчётность всё одно не попадают.

Comment: @teran однозначно могу сказать, что будет еще поле `store_id`, но оно идет для всех типов данных. Поскольку точек 3, то нужно указывать, о какой точке идет речь.